# Show that $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ is not a $C^*$-algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

I am currenctly working with some training exercises in operator algebra. I have to show that $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ is not a $C^\ast$-algebra for the following involution defined as $(x^\ast)_n:=\overline{x_{-n}}$.

What I have in mind is that we can use the following
$$x_n:=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1, & \text{ if } n=0\;\;\;\;\\ 
-2, & \text{ if } n=1,2\\ 
0, & \text{ otherwise }
\end{matrix}\right.$$
And now my goal is to show that it is not a $C^\ast$-algebra. Anyone who can help me to continue?

Comment: What do you want to do with such $\{x_n\}$ ? Any plan ?

Comment: What is the definition of a $C^\star$ algebra for you ?

Comment: What I try to do is to make a contradiction with the identity but I am not sure how to compute the norms. I.e.
$||x^\ast \ast x||_1$ and $||x||_1^2$. What I want is to get different numbers.

Comment: ok so, $\ell^1$ is equipped with $\vert \vert\cdot \vert\vert_1$. You may have to specify this in your question as it may have been equipped with a $C^\star$ norm.

Comment: So what are those numbers ?

Comment: I have additional information. We equip $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ with the norm $||(x_n)_n||:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|x_n|$.

Comment: Sure, this is $\vert \vert \cdot \vert\vert_1$

Comment: I don't know with the numbers that you are asking for. I know I have to contradict something but I cannot see my way out of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131460/discussion-between-infinitelooper-and-joey-adams).

Answer (score 2):

I assume the product on $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$ is the pointwise product.

If it makes a $C^*$-algebra, then $\|xx^*\|=\sum_n |x_n\overline {x_{-n}}| = \|x\|^2$ for all $x$.

It's easy to find a counter example for this equality.

E.g. let $(x_n) = \chi_{\{0, 1\}}$ be the characteristic function of $\{0, 1\}$, then $\sum_n |x_n \bar x_{-n}|=1$ but $\|x\|^2= 2^2=4$.

Comment: Interesting. We define $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z}):=\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}:x_n\in\mathbb{C},\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|x_n|<+\infty\}$.  A quick question which might be simple but how do you get 2 when computing the norm? Is it just the number of elements $\{0,1\}$ or am I wrong?

Comment: It's just $|1| + |1|$ where the first $1$ is the coefficient for $0$ and the second is for $1$.

Comment: BTW, the convolution can also make a Banach algebra out of $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$, which is still not a $C^*$-algebra for similar reasons. (I saw you used $x^**x$ in the comment, but I'm not sure whether you mean convolution by $*$ in the middle.